# Particle swarm algorithm with multiple threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I wrote a simple multitthreading program which does particle swarm optimization. Optimization itself and some corresponding functions were taken from https://nathanrooy.github.io/posts/2016-08-17/simple-particle-swarm-optimization-with-python/. This is my first attempt to write multithread Python code :)

Code has 4 files:

1. **const.py** - just some constants
2. **main.py** - entry point
3. **particle.py** particle class as a thread
4. **particle_producer** - class which synchronizes all particles and computes next position/velocity

Thank you for your help :)

const.py

```
MAX_ITERATIONS = 300
NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES = 10
NUM_DIMENSIONS = 2
```

main.py

```
import threading
import random

from consts import NUM_DIMENSIONS, NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES
from particle import Particle
from particle_producer import ParticleSwarmProducer

import numpy as np


# Function to optimize
def fnc(x):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        total+=x[i]**2
    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_down, x_up = (-100, 100)

    # All shared datastrucures between particles and particle producer
    dict_shared_new_position = {i: list(np.random.uniform(x_down, x_up, NUM_DIMENSIONS)) for i in range(0, NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES)}
    dict_shared_best_position = dict_shared_new_position.copy()
    dict_velocity = {i: [random.uniform(-1,1)] * NUM_DIMENSIONS for i in range(0, NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES)}
    dict_shared_errors = {i: -1 for i in range(0, NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES)}
    dict_shared_is_ready = {i: False for i in range(0, NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES)}

    bounds = [(x_down, x_up) for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES)]

    condition_wait = threading.Condition()


    producer = ParticleSwarmProducer(initial_particle_position=dict_shared_new_position,
                                     bounds=bounds,
                                     dict_shared_errors=dict_shared_errors,
                                     dict_shared_is_ready=dict_shared_is_ready,
                                     dict_shared_new_position=dict_shared_new_position,
                                     dict_shared_best_positions=dict_shared_best_position,
                                     dict_velocity=dict_velocity,
                                     condition_wait=condition_wait
                                     )

    particles = []

    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES):
        p = Particle(thread_id=i,
                     name='Thread ' + str(i+1),
                     dict_shared_errors=dict_shared_errors,
                     dict_shared_is_ready=dict_shared_is_ready,
                     dict_shared_new_position=dict_shared_new_position,
                     dict_shared_best_positions=dict_shared_best_position,
                     fnc=fnc,
                     condition_wait=condition_wait)
        particles.append(p)

    producer.start()

    for p in particles:
        p.start()

    producer.join()

    for p in particles:
        p.join()
```

particle.py

```
import threading

from consts import MAX_ITERATIONS

threadLock = threading.Lock()


class Particle(threading.Thread):
    """ Represents one particle object with specific position/velocity"""
    def __init__(self,
                 thread_id,
                 name,
                 dict_shared_errors,
                 dict_shared_is_ready,
                 dict_shared_new_position,
                 dict_shared_best_positions,
                 fnc,
                 condition_wait
                 ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.name = name

        self.dict_shared_errors = dict_shared_errors
        self.dict_shared_is_ready = dict_shared_is_ready
        self.dict_shared_new_positions = dict_shared_new_position
        self.dict_shared_best_positions = dict_shared_best_positions

        self.fnc = fnc
        self.condition_wait = condition_wait

    def run(self) -> None:

        it = 1
        best_particle_error = 9999

        while it < MAX_ITERATIONS+1:
            # print(f'{self.name} waiting for a new job...')
            threadLock.acquire(blocking=True)
            self.dict_shared_is_ready[self.thread_id] = True
            threadLock.release()

            with self.condition_wait:
                self.condition_wait.wait()

            threadLock.acquire(blocking=True)
            position = self.dict_shared_new_positions[self.thread_id]
            error = self.fnc(position)

            if error < best_particle_error:
                self.dict_shared_best_positions[self.thread_id] = position
                best_particle_error = error

            self.dict_shared_errors[self.thread_id] = self.fnc(position)

            # set to not ready
            self.dict_shared_is_ready[self.thread_id] = False
            threadLock.release()
            # print(f'{self.name} working on task')
            it +=1
            # print(f'{self.name}, {it}')
```

particle_producer.py

```
    import threading
    import time
    import random
    import numpy as np
    
    from consts import NUM_DIMENSIONS, NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES, MAX_ITERATIONS
    
    threadLock = threading.Lock()
    
    
    class ParticleSwarmProducer(threading.Thread):
        """ Synchronizes all particles and computes their next position/velocity"""
        def __init__(self,
                     initial_particle_position,
                     bounds,
                     dict_shared_errors,
                     dict_shared_is_ready,
                     dict_shared_new_position,
                     dict_shared_best_positions,
                     dict_velocity,
                     condition_wait):
    
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    
            self.initial_particle_positions = initial_particle_position
            self.bounds = bounds
    
            self.dict_velocity = dict_velocity
    
            self.dict_best_positions = dict_shared_best_positions
            self.dict_shared_errors = dict_shared_errors
            self.dict_shared_is_ready = dict_shared_is_ready
            self.dict_shared_new_position = dict_shared_new_position
    
            self.condition_wait = condition_wait
    
            self.current_iteration = 0
            self.err_best_g = -1  # best error for group
            self.pos_best_g = []  # best position for group
    
            # Used for plotting
            self.output_pos = {i: np.empty((0, NUM_DIMENSIONS)) for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES)}
    
        def run(self) -> None:
    
            i = 1
            while i < MAX_ITERATIONS+1:
                threadLock.acquire(blocking=True)
                ready = list(self.dict_shared_is_ready.values())
    
                # If all particles have finished their current jobs...
                if all(ready):
                    print(f'Iteration {i}')
                    print(f'Current positions: {self.dict_shared_new_position}')
                    print(f'Current errors: {self.dict_shared_errors}')
                    print(f'Current velocities: {self.dict_velocity}')
    
                    self.add_pos_to_out()
    
                    self.evaluate_all_particles()
                    self.update_all_particles()
    
                    print('All particles go!')
    
                    with self.condition_wait:
                        self.condition_wait.notifyAll()
                    i += 1
                threadLock.release()
                # time.sleep(0.2)
    
                time.sleep(0.02)
            with self.condition_wait:
                self.condition_wait.notifyAll()
            print(f'Current positions: {self.dict_shared_new_position}')
            print(f'Error: {self.err_best_g}')
    
    
        def evaluate_all_particles(self):
            for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES):
                if self.dict_shared_errors[i] < self.err_best_g or self.err_best_g == -1:
                    self.pos_best_g = list(self.dict_shared_new_position[i])
                    self.err_best_g = float(self.dict_shared_errors[i])
    
        def update_all_particles(self):
            for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES):
                self.update_velocity(i)
                self.update_position(i)
    
        def add_pos_to_out(self):
            for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PARTICLES):
                self.output_pos[i] = np.vstack((self.output_pos[i], self.dict_shared_new_position[i]))
    
        def update_velocity(self, i):
            w = 0.5  # constant inertia weight (how much to weigh the previous velocity)
            c1 = 1  # cognative constant
            c2 = 2  # social constant
    
            for j in range(0, NUM_DIMENSIONS):
                r1 = random.random()
                r2 = random.random()
    
                vel_cognitive = c1 * r1 * (self.dict_best_positions[i][j] - self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j])
                vel_social = c2 * r2 * (self.pos_best_g[j] - self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j])
    
                self.dict_velocity[i][j] = w * self.dict_velocity[i][j] + vel_cognitive + vel_social
    
        def update_position(self, i):
            for j in range(0, NUM_DIMENSIONS):
                self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j] = self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j] + self.dict_velocity[i][j]
    
                # adjust maximum position if necessary
                if self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j] > self.bounds[i][1]:
                    self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j] = self.bounds[i][1]
    
                # adjust minimum position if neseccary
                if self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j] < self.bounds[i][0]:
                    self.dict_shared_new_position[i][j] = self.bounds[i][0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Run the code through `black` and `isort --profile=black` to format it more idiomatically without any manual work.
2. Run the code through `flake8` or `pylint` to check for other maintainability issues.
3. Run the code through `mypy`, ideally with a [strict configuration](https://github.com/stac-utils/pystac/blob/e2239a73eff9dbf5b41660f19370c1a6c376e387/mypy.ini), and annotate accordingly. It'll help readers make sense of the arguments and return values, and makes type prefixes like `dict_` redundant.
4. Code should ideally be grouped according to what it belongs with, rather than what it *is.* For example, you wouldn't group all classes in one file, so why group all the constants?
5. `i = 1; while i < MAX_ITERATIONS+1:` can be simplified as `for iteration in range(1, MAX_ITERATIONS + 1)`, or more idiomatically, `for index in range(MAX_ITERATIONS)`.
6. `range(0, limit)` can be simplified to `range(limit)`.

[cat overflow. please hold.]